# mongoose populate no trabaja a 3 niveles

Tags: moongose, populate

Buenas tengo el siguiente esquema y necesito hacer populate a productos.agregos.agrego
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola, completa el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento general del sitio. Luego, edita la pregunta con la información que hay en [ask], donde encontrarás recomendaciones para mejorar tus preguntas y facilitar que otros usuarios te ayuden. Un saludo.